# User cannot view the report even though the report folder is shared with the user

Tags: reporting, sharing, custom-report-type

We want to share a report with a particular user called A in salesforce. So we have placed the report in one folder and shared the folder to the user A and assigned the permission called 'Viewer'.

Whenever the user tries to view the report  he is getting insufficient privileges error.

May I know why he cannot view the report eventhough it is shared with the user?

Comment: Does the permission set have access to the object and all fields used within the report?

Comment: Hi Dan Jones, you were right.

Comment: Perfect. I've written it as an answer, marking it as correct may help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found out, the User didn't have access to the Objects and Fields used within the report thus throwing an insufficient privileges error.

When creating reports, users will need access to not only the folder the report exists in, but also fields and objects contained inside the report.